# Where is VSCode's "Restart TS server"?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm new to TS. I'm seeing instructions to use the command panel to"Restart TS server".

But this option is not there.

Is this a particular extension?

Answer (score 197):

1. You'll need to have a `.js`, `.ts` or `.tsx` file focused in the editor.
2. Then Open the command palette

   - **Mac**: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
   - **Win**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
3. Then type `restart` and the option should be available.

   [image: screenshot]

Comment: it doesnt show up for me. Do you know what could've gone wrong?

Comment: NOTE: Make sure you're not on a diff (working tree view) as that won't trigger the option in the menu

Comment: if it is possible vscode should allow you to trigger restart of ts server even if you are on a diff as long as it is a `.js`, `.ts` or `.tsx` file

Comment: For the Vue devs out there: if you use Volar, the command to restart the server is "Volar: Restart Vue server". Relevant GitHub comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155785#issuecomment-1190870464

Comment: The "TypeScript: Restart TS Server" command didn't appear for me until I enabled "Tsserver: Use Syntax Server" in user settings. Its JSON config is: `"typescript.tsserver.useSyntaxServer": "always"`.

Comment: It also doesn't appear if you are currently looking at a non-typescript file. Which is irritating, but.

Answer (score 14):

check if you have randomly disabled  `typescript and javascript language features` builtin extension.

Switch to extensions tab and search with `@builtin`.

Find it and Enable it!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was my case on a WSL 2 install, doing this allowed back all intelisense functionality again in JS and TS

Comment: Thank you - I wasted 2 hours searching internet and various trial&error for the same issue till I landed here.

Comment: How is this NOT the accepted answer?? I wasted 5 hours and a LOT of hair over this.
Thanks a lot  @Liu CZ

Comment: Comparing to the other comments I was lucky and only wasted ~30 minutes. Still: Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had been working on merging 7 React apps into **Turborepo** monorepos, and was troubled by the fact that `tsconfig/.eslintrc` could not reflect in real-time when I made changes to them, so I built this small extension to monitor those config files and restart **TypeScript / ESLint servers** accordingly.

**Link to the VS Code extension:**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neotan.vscode-auto-restart-typescript-eslint-servers

## vscode-auto-restart-typescript-eslint-servers

Restart TypeScript or ESLint server automatically if monitored configuration or files changed.

[image: Banner]

### Features

- Restart TypeScript and ESLint servers automatically
- Enable/Disable files monitoring

### Credits

- [vscode-restart-ts-server-button](https://github.com/qcz/vscode-restart-ts-server-button) by Qcz
- [vscode-eslint](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint) by Microsoft