# Typescript - Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript

I created a new project using create-react-app and yarn 2 in vs code. The editor throws errors while importing every installed library like this:

> Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.

The project compiles and runs successfully but the errors are still there. When I change the file's extension to *.js* and *.jsx* from.*ts* and *.tsx*, the errors disappear. How should I solve this problem for typescript files?

Answer (score 115):

You need to install types for libraries you install. generally you should do:

```
npm install @types/libName // e.g. npm install @types/react-leaflet
```

Some times there's no types available in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repo and you encounter `npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @types/my-untyped-module@latest`. You can do several things in this occasion:

**1-** Create a `decs.d.ts` file in root of your project and write in it:

```
    declare module "libName" // e.g declare module 'react-leaflet'
```

**2-** Or simply suppress the error using `@ts-ignore`:

```
// @ts-ignore  
import Map from 'react-leaflet'
```

**3-** Or you can do yourself and others a favor and add the library types in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-can-i-contribute) repo.

If it still doesn't work, I firstly recommend that you use a recent version of Typescript. if you do, then close your editor, delete `node_modules` folder and install the dependencies again (`npm install` or `yarn install`) and check it again.

Comment: It's already installed for react, but the problem is still established.

Comment: @AmirFakhimBabaei you must do it for every installed library.

Comment: "Create a decs.d.ts file in root of your project and write in it" ... which project?  The project for my dependent module or the project that includes it???

Comment: @StartupGuy Your project which includes the module without ts types.

Comment: wow.  it's 2021 and we're doing *.d.ts files.  React gives you a sparkplug and tells you that you can build a car.  yeah.  ok. it's a super framework.

Comment: I'd like to include my own js file. How to solve this?

Comment: Using option #2 works for me.
// @ts-ignore

Answer (score 105):

#### Maybe just restarting the TS server can work.

**Using VsCode:**

**Windows:**

type: `ctrl + Shift + P` or `ctrl + Shift + F5`

choose: `> TypeScript: Restart TS server`

**Macbook:**

type: `⇧ + ⌘ + P` or `F1`

choose: `> TypeScript: Restart TS server`

#### Maybe it's just a file error, check if you accidentally changed a file from `.ts` to `.tsx` or `.tsx` to `.ts`

Comment: It works for me. But im searching for the solution that will help me to fix this issue without restarting ts server in vscode

Comment: @cyberfrogg Maybe was just some bug in vs code, this happens a lot. I think you don't need to worry too much about it.

Comment: This ts error mentioned in the question happened to me after removing and installing node modules. Restarting the ts server worked, thanks  a lot.

Comment: I lol'd when this was the suggestion then did it and it worked :shrug:

Comment: I had this problem with the chatgpt npm module and this answer fixed it thanks.

Comment: This, I accidentally changed a file from `.ts` to `.tsx` and then changed it back. Simply had to restart my bundler

Comment: Note, to restart the TS server in VsCode, you should have a .ts or .tsx file open before doing what this comment suggests. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454845/where-is-vscodes-restart-ts-server

Comment: Simply reloading VSCode is often a solution.

Answer (score 45):

I had the same error message, also related to the imports.

In my case, the problem was caused by importing a png file in order to use it in an SVG:

```
import logo from 'url:../../public/img/logo.png';
```

The message I received was:

```
Cannot find module 'url:../..public/img/logo.png' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

#### Solution:

In project root is a file `css.d.ts`. One must declare a module for the various graphics extensions (types) that are imported. *(Note: Not for graphics types that are used or referenced in the project, but for those that are* ***imported*** *)*

Here is the complete `css.d.ts` file for this project:

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const css: { [key: string]: string };
  export default css;
}
declare module '*.sass' {
  const css: { [key: string]: string };
  export default css;
}
declare module 'react-markup';
declare module '*.webp';
declare module '*.png';
declare module '*.jpg';
declare module '*.jpeg';
```

Comment: maybe this comment can help guide people here working in Sapper (Svelte) projects: using Typescript in Sapper, a file `src/ambient.d.ts` will be generated that will already declare types for a couple of extensions. That is the perfect place to add yours.

Comment: @SillyFreak Thanks, great feedback. Please feel free to take this answer and create from it your own answer exactly as you suggest. Go right ahead and create a new answer in the Sapper / Svelte tag categories and borrow from this answer as necessary to help your fellow Sappers. This way, you will know the exact wording of the error messages or other key words that would bring googlers to your answer. *Meilleurs voeux!*

Comment: As noted by @Najathi, if `css.d.ts` (or whatever you call it) isn't included in the `tsconfig.json` `"include": [...]` array the ts server won't pick it up.

Answer (score 14):

my situation:

`myFolder` is under the `src` dir

I see the same error in this line:

```
import { GlobalStyle } from "myFolder";
```

other answers dont work.

I simply add `baseUrl` to `tsconfig.json` inside `compilerOptions`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src/",
//other config...
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

issue solved!

ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl

Answer (score 6):

I have deleted one module and added back it to my source code. Although the same source code is there, due to caching I am getting this error.

Below Solution works for me:

Windows:

> `ctrl + Shift + F5`

Macbook:

> ⇧ + ⌘  + P ***OR***  F1

[image]

Comment:  Looks like my answer haha, but yeah this worked for me too bro +1 

Comment: @Erick Willian  (⇧ + ⌘ + P OR F1 ) <- Write this line to your solution, after that might be our solution look the same.

Comment: Any idea why I don't see this option? Do I have to install an extension for that? I would assume VSCode offers this by default?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed my issue

1. create file `/types/css.d.ts`
2. open `tsconfig.json`

add this object:

```
"include": [
    "src",
    "types"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem for myself using the following import ..."/index.cjs": import { MRT_Localization_RU } from "mantine-react-table/locales/en/index.cjs";

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependencies object in package.json file.
If the install package is in the format "@somepackage/packagename":version;
then at the time of import you must use
import abc from "@somepackage/packagename"

If "@somepackage/" is not there then don't use it at the time of import.
Just simply use
import abc from "packagename";

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had my file named `index.tsx` whereas it should have been with capital `I`, so `Index.tsx`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just an autocomplete import (like "@reduxjs/toolkit/src/query/tests/mocks/server") done by the VS Code that I didn't notice while commiting

Answer (score 0):

This can still happen with newest versions of yarn + PnP, due to a known bug. [Source](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/5125)

1. Remove previous SDKs typescript folder, if present on `.yarn/sdks/typescript`
2. Install previous supported TS version: `yarn add typescript@4.7`
3. Add the new editor SDKs: `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`. You can append vim o whichever [supported SDKs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks).
4. Restart your IDE

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers... when importing the module be sure to not mix single and double quotes.

❌ `import A from 'test"`
✅ `import A from 'test'`
✅ `import A from "test"`

Comment: IMO mixing is ok for TS engine itself (although you should probably use linter/formatter to enforce style)... Changing the quotes probably forced TS to rescan the modules.

Comment: this has literally not one thing to do with parsing. single- and double-quoted string literals are the same thing

Comment: last time i checked (1 minute ago) it gave me an error :/. You probably didn't understand my answer so i edited it by adding one more example