# ESLint causes issues with imports in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm trying to get eslint set up in vscode with my project.  That said, I have the following eslintrc.json file in the root of my project:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {}
}
```

However, with that configuration, I'm seeing lots of errors on my import lines for my files.  For example, I see the following on the line with the import for React:

```
Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Needless to say, this is disheartening because I'm working in a react project.  Also, the project still starts up and runs as it should, which leads me to believe this is a vscode issue.  Any advise on how to make the errors in vscode go away would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is an ESLint issue and not a typescript issue?
Does your package.json have a reference to [@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react)?
See [React, Typescript - Cannot find module … or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64732623/react-typescript-cannot-find-module-or-its-corresponding-type-declaration). Also, what type of files are you seeing these errors in: `js`, `jsx`, `ts` or `tsx`?

Comment: I'm not sure of that at all.  What I do know for sure is that following an install and setup of ESLint in my project with the above configuration, I suddenly began to see errors on the import lines in my project.

Comment: Also, I'm seeing these errors in .tsx files.

Comment: Please try @logan-devine's answer and let us know if this resolves the issue. As this is what I was suggesting as well.

Answer (score 0):

This error is not ESLint related, nor VSCode related. It is a warning from TypeScript's type checker, saying one of the following:

- `react` is not installed; **or**
- `react` does not have a `.d.ts` typedefs file.

In your case, as the code runs, it's the second one. React does not have a definitions file, so you need to **install** the DefinitelyTyped package for React via `npm install --save-dev @types/react` or `yarn add --dev @types/react`.

**NOTE:** If you are making a typedef file for your project (not needed unless it's a library or you are augmenting types) and you need to import `@types/react` from your definition file, you need to leave out the `--save-dev`/`--dev` part.

Comment: Why would these errors suddenly appear following the addition of the above configuration then?  Previous to adding eslint to the project, my imports were fine.

Comment: This is a TypeScript error. Not sure why it came up after installing ESLint however. Run the install command I showed and it will be fixed.