# React Typescript - Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations even after creating declaration

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use `collections/sorted-map` in my React TS project. `sorted-map` doesn't have a declaration. I found out that I need to create my own `sorted-map.d.ts` declaration ([React, Typescript - Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64732623/react-typescript-cannot-find-module-or-its-corresponding-type-declaratio)).

Luckily there is a declaration for `sorted-set` which is part of `sorted-map` so it should be relatively easy.

The problem is - even after creating `sorted-map.d.ts` I still get the same error:

> Cannot find module 'collections/sorted-map' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-mountain-seub1?file=/src/App.tsx)

`src/sorted-map.d.ts`:

```js
import {SortedSet} from "collections/sorted-set"

declare module 'collections/sorted-map'
// declare const SortedMap: internal.SortedMapStatic;

declare namespace SortedMap {
    type Iterator<T> = internal.Iterator<T>;
    type SortedMap<T> = internal.SortedMap<T>;
}

declare namespace internal {
    interface SortedMapStatic {
        <T>(
            values?: T[],
            equals?: (a: T, b: T) => boolean,
            compare?: (a: T, b: T) => number,
            getDefault?: any,
        ): SortedMap<T>;
        new <T>(
            values?: T[],
            equals?: (a: T, b: T) => boolean,
            compare?: (a: T, b: T) => number,
            getDefault?: any,
        ): SortedMap<T>;
    }

    class Iterator<T> {
        constructor(set: SortedMap<T>, start?: T, end?: T);
        next(): { done: boolean; value: T | undefined };
    }

    class SortedMap<T> {
        readonly length: number;

        constructor(values?: T[], equals?: (a: T, b: T) => boolean, compare?: (a: T, b: T) => number, getDefault?: any);
        constructClone(values?: T[]): SortedMap<T>;
        iterate(): Iterator<T>;
        store: SortedSet<T>;
    }
}

export = SortedMap;
```

`App.tsx`:

```js
import { SortedMap } from "collections/sorted-map";

export default function App() {
  return <div>Test</div>;
}
```