# Vercel not deolpying on github repo

Tags: deployment, node-modules, vercel

I am using vercel to deploy and I am getting this error, Jem and lib are both local packages that are installed like so `"jem": "file:../lib",` and `"lib": "file:../lib",`. this is my vercel settings. This is working on my local deployment with the vercel cli but not working when I use the Github production. any help would be great. Not I am using svelte.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this a public repo? if so can you share link to the OR where deployment is failing?

Comment: @bcstryker sadly no it's not and I can not

Comment: @bcstryker I have got a demo working with the a deployment strait from the VSC project but when I try and build the project from github it does not work(note: exactly the same code and node modules are not installed on both so both need to install the dependents.)

Comment: I answered but it might be wrong. The one you have running, is it running in dev? or build > start?

Comment: Try the answer I added, but if that doesn't work try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64732623/react-typescript-cannot-find-module-or-its-corresponding-type-declaration

Answer (score 0):

You need to install types for libraries you install. Try this:

`npm install @types/jem`

Comment: how do I add this? just in the install command? Also I am running it in build

Comment: How do I add this to my deployment on vercel?

Comment: sorry! you should be able to just issue this command in cli of the project root directory. it should either create or edit files to the project.