# Why md5 import is wrong in React?

Tags: reactjs, md5

Why import wrong here? Got this error:

```
Issues checking in progress...
ERROR in src/slices/Campaign.ts:3:17
TS2307: Cannot find module 'md5' or its corresponding type declarations.
    1 | import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    2 | import axios from "axios";
  > 3 | import md5 from "md5";
      |                 ^^^^^
    4 |
    5 | // Actions
    6 |
```

```
// package.json
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "md5-hash": "^1.0.1",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.11",
```

```js
import md5 from "md5";

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: `api/image`,
  data: {
    filename: imageFilename,
    md5: md5(imageFilename), 
  },
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, Typescript - Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64732623/react-typescript-cannot-find-module-or-its-corresponding-type-declaration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [@types/md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/md5), a package that contains type definitions for [md5](https://github.com/pvorb/node-md5).

Packages under the `@types` scope are from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), a community driven effort to provide typescript types for popular JS packages.

This is the type definition for the md5 package: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/md5/index.d.ts

Comment: And need { md5 }, strange why.