# NestJs with typescript error - Cannot find module '@nestjs/core' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: visual-studio-code, nestjs, yarn-v2

While trying to bootstrap a new NestJs project with Yarn 3 in Vscode I'm getting the following compilation error :

```
Cannot find module '@nestjs/core' or its corresponding type declarations
```

and also for the `@nestjs/common` package

[image]

I ran yarn install for that package and it exists in .yarn/cache but it seems like the project cannot locate packages by Yarn's PnP, or something in vscode is misconfigured.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

How did you create the project ?.

Did you generate it automatically using the commands specified on the [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps) website ?

```js
$ npm i -g @nestjs/cli
$ nest new project-name
```

Also, are you sure you did yarn install in the correct directory and made sure that the `package.json` contains the `@nestjs/common` and `@nestjs/core` dependencies ?

If none of those suggestions work maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64732623/react-typescript-cannot-find-module-or-its-corresponding-type-declaration) can help