# Cannot find existing installed module or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, npm, typescript-typings

I have a typescript react project and is working fine. I am not sure, how the app was created!. The project use both tippy.js and react-paginate modules on different pages for rendering calendar and pagination controls. Once my api returns pagination response on that page with pagination control, it breaks another page with calendar control, not the page with pagination control!. The page with pagination control works fine with hard-coded data and I assume it is only the pagination response breaking another page but not sure how and I would appreciate if someone help identify and fix the issue.

The API's response looks like this:

```
return {
    tasks,
    pagination: {
      currentPage: options.page || 1,
      numberofRecordsPerPage: limit,
      totalPages : Math.ceil(recordCount/limit),
      totalRecords : recordCount
    }
  }
```

and the error message is:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@tippy.js' in '\src\components\calendar'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css' in 'src\components\calendar'

and the import statements are:

```
// @ts-ignore
    import tippy from "@tippy.js";

    // @ts-ignore
    import "tippy.js/dist/tippy.css";
```

I read another article [Typescript - Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64732623/typescript-cannot-find-module-or-its-corresponding-type-declarations) with similar issue and tried all those fixes but none of them helped me to resolve the issue.

I would appreciate if there is any help

I tried clean up and and added any missing reference to types and none of these helped

```
npm install @types/libName
npm install --save-dev style-loader
npm install --save-dev css-loader
declare module tippy
// @ts-ignore 
rm node_modules -r
npm install
ctrl + shift + p
```

created decs.d.ts file within the project's root folder

```
declare module '*.css' {
      const css: { [key: string]: string };
      export default css;
    }
```