# TypeScript: Module '"@nestjs/typeorm"' has no exported member 'TypeOrmModule' What is causing this?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have installed all necessary packages to use typeorm for my mysql database but I keep getting
`Module '"@nestjs/typeorm"' has no exported member 'TypeOrmModule'.` when I start my server.
Why?

Here are my dev dependencies in the package.json file.

```
dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.0.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "github:nestjs/typeorm",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.37"
  },
```

Here is my database.module.ts file where I am supposed to consume the TypeOrmModule.

```
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot()],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})
export class DatabaseModule {
  constructor(connection: Connection) {
    if (connection.isConnected) console.log('connected successfully!');
  }
}
```

I have run npm install again to see if it will fix it but I still get the same error. Any one know what is wrong?

Comment: did you tried using `"@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2"` instead?

Comment: Hey @MicaelLevi thanks but that didn't workout for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was a hierarchy issue in my `database.module.ts` file. The TypeOrmModule was supposed to be under the parent Module of nestjs for it to be recognized. TypeScript is strict when it comes to this.

It was supposed to be like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
```

Not this:

```
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'; 
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
```

I hope this solves anyone facing the same issue because it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to use Like inside the TypeORM find({}) method,

```
import { Like } from '@nestjs/typeorm';   
    this.bugRepository.find({
        verson: Like(`%${query.version}`)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, restarting the TypeScript server solves the problem.

"ctrl + shift + p" and select "TypeScript: Restart TS Server"

[how to restart Typescript server in "vscode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454845/where-is-vscodes-restart-ts-server)