# flatMap still doesn't work in typescript even after target and lib set in tsconfig

Tags: typescript

I've tried some bable settings, different target/lib settings in tsconfig, nothing. Not sure what else I can do...

The errors look like this where:

```
  let test:object[] = [{}];
  test.flatMap();

Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'object[]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2019' or later.ts(2550)
```

& my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "public",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "public"]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to change `target` to `es2020`?

Comment: yes, exact same error. It almost as if anything I change in tsconfig, no file recognises the change in the files.

Comment: After changing stuff, are you getting the error after you build or on your IDE? Have you tried restarting the TS server in your IDE? Sometimes config changes don't reflect easily

Comment: @maazadeeb derp. restarting the ts server fixed it. If you add an answer I can confirm that's correct. I have had other changes in the tsconfig that when I rebuilt they worked, it seems target/lib changes require a server restart.

Comment: Possible workaround:  if you add `lodash` (and optionally `@types/lodash`) to your `package.json` , it adds `flatMap` as well as a ton of other convenient functions to your arrays. (e.g. `uniq` to filter duplicate values from arrays, `groupBy` to group array values using a key-attribute.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes to `tsconfig` don't reflect in IDEs sometimes. Depending on your IDE, you should be able to find a way to restart the TypeScript server. If you can't find it, then you could just restart your IDE itself.

How to do it on VSCode: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64454845/2950032)