# How to include modules in client side in typescript projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm making a typescript project for client side javascript code.

Before I was using typescript, I imported a module like this (this is vanilla js in es6)

`import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';`

but with typescript, I installed the module with `npm install` and then import it like this

`import * as THREE from 'three';`

Problem is, when I then run the compiled js code, I get this browser js error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

since `import * as THREE from 'three';` is now in the compiled js files.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

[image]

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist/",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ESNext",
        "lib": [
            "ESNext", "DOM"
        ],
        "allowJs": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/",
        "src/**/*.json"
    ],
    "exclude": [

    ]
}
```

Comment: What does your project structure look like? Do you have a package.json? A tsconfig.json?

Comment: How are you compiling it? Chances are, you need to compile AND bundle, so that your bundler will literally bundle the NPM dependencies into the compiled code.

Comment: I have added my project structure and tsconfig.

Comment: Can you include your package.json? You should also try restarting the ts server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454845/where-is-vscodes-restart-ts-server

Answer (score 3):

> This assumes you are using TypeScript to compile isolated ES modules destined for use in the browser, loaded in HTML tags like `<script type="module" src="myCompiledModule.js">`. From your question details, it sounds like this is the case.

Although not entirely straightforward, it's relatively simple to accomplish this:

In order to satisfy the compiler, make sure you have installed both `typescript` and `@types/three`:

```
npm install typescript @types/three
```

Then, add this [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) to your `./tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js": ["node_modules/@types/three"]
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Here's the full config I'm using to test this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js": ["node_modules/@types/three"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Now, you'll have the correct types for `THREE` in the modules where it is imported using the specifier `"https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js"`. For example, when I type `THREE.Mesh`, TypeScript IntelliSense shows me that it's this type:

```
class Mesh<TGeometry extends THREE.BufferGeometry = THREE.BufferGeometry, TMaterial extends THREE.Material | THREE.Material[] = THREE.Material | THREE.Material[]>
```

Here's the example module in my test:

`./src/index.ts`:

```ts
import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';
console.log(THREE);
```

Now, when you compile your project using `tsc`, you'll get this output, which is a valid ECMAScript module and will use the "three" module imported from the hosted URL:

`./dist/index.js`:

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';
console.log(THREE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this on the client side, a bundler would be needed.

I suggest webpack or snowpack. Snowpack is new and has a lot of very cool features.

Comment: It would be good if you explain, how to use a builder like webpack, how it transpiles TS to JS, which is served to clients. Some links would be also helpful. Thanks.