# VS Code reporting TypeScript errors after update

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, types, material-ui

Since updating VS Code I'm getting TypeScript error messages like

> `ButtonUnstyled.types.d.ts: Module '"/components/node_modules/@types/react/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag ts(1259) [Ln 1,Col 8].`
> `index.d.ts[Ln 65, Col 1]: This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.`

All of the erros, in JSON format:

```js
/* eslint-disable indent */
[{
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/ButtonUnstyled/ButtonUnstyled.types.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
  }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/InputUnstyled/InputUnstyledProps.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
    }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/OptionGroupUnstyled/OptionGroupUnstyled.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
    }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/OptionGroupUnstyled/OptionGroupUnstyledProps.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
    }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/OptionUnstyled/OptionUnstyled.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
    }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/OptionUnstyled/OptionUnstyledProps.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
    }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/SelectUnstyled/useSelect.types.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
    }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/TabPanelUnstyled/TabPanelUnstyledProps.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
    }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/TabsListUnstyled/TabsListUnstyledProps.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
    }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/TabsUnstyled/TabsUnstyledProps.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
    }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/base/utils/isHostComponent.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1259",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/react/index' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 13,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 65,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: 65,
      endColumn: 16,
      message: "This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.",
      resource: "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"
    }]
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/utils/chainPropTypes.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1192",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/prop-types/index' has no default export.",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 17
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/utils/elementAcceptingRef.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1192",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/prop-types/index' has no default export.",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 17
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/utils/elementTypeAcceptingRef.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1192",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/prop-types/index' has no default export.",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 17
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@mui/utils/refType.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "1192",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Module 'node_modules/@types/prop-types/index' has no default export.",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 8,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 17
}, {
  resource: "node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts",
  owner: "typescript",
  code: "2403",
  severity: 8,
  message: "Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'AbortSignal' must be of type '{ new (): AbortSignal; prototype: AbortSignal; abort(reason?: any): AbortSignal; timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal; }', but here has type '{ new (): AbortSignal; prototype: AbortSignal; }'.",
  source: "ts",
  startLineNumber: 72,
  startColumn: 13,
  endLineNumber: 72,
  endColumn: 24,
  relatedInformation: [{
      startLineNumber: 2304,
      startColumn: 13,
      endLineNumber: 2304,
      endColumn: 24,
      message: "'AbortSignal' was also declared here.",
      resource: "/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.1.20230405/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts"
    }]
}];
```

But when I open `ButtonUnstyled.types.d.ts` the errors disappear. When I close it they'll show up again. Even when the `tsconfig.json` has set `"esModuleInterop": true`. So it seems not to be considered. Any ideas how to turn this off?

VS Code version is

```
Version: 1.77.1
Commit: b7886d7461186a5eac768481578c1d7ca80e2d21
Date: 2023-04-04T23:23:33.779Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0
Sandboxed: No
```

TypeScript Version is

```
5.1.0-dev.20230405
```

MUI versions are

```
├── @mui/icons-material@5.6.0
├── @mui/material@5.6.0
├── @mui/styles@5.6.0
├── @mui/x-date-pickers@5.0.2
```

Comment: "_Even when the tsconfig.json has set "esModuleInterop": true. So it seems not to be considered._" what if you restart VS Code after making that tsconfig change? sometimes a restart is necessary.

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/q/41702815/11107541 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, a mix of [changing the TypeScript version of VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668731/what-typescript-version-is-visual-studio-code-using-how-to-update-it/39676463#39676463), [restarting the TS Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454845/where-is-vscodes-restart-ts-server) and restarting VS Code fixed the issue at that time.