# Visual Studio is highlighting imports with @

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, volar

I have this project in Vue3, TS, Vite
and in VS Code (Typescript Vue Plugin (Volar), Vue 3 Snippets, Vue Language Features (Volar)) I have recently been getting this weird import error

```
import InputText from '@/components/form/InputText.vue';
```

When used this, I am getting -> `Cannot find module '@/components/form/InputText.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

even tho the import is successful and the app works fine ...

when I change it to relative path -> `import InputText from '../form/InputText.vue'` it works fine ...

any idea what could possibly happen and how to fix it? it's not causing any issues but visually drives me nuts

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.node.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["vite.config.*", "vitest.config.*", "cypress.config.*", "nightwatch.conf.*", "playwright.config.*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

SOLUTION:

Found it .... I was missing `files: [],` in my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you alias the `@` path in your tsconfig? [these instructions may help](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-path-aliases-cleaner-react-typescript-imports#configuring-path-aliases-tsconfigjson-file)

Comment: yes it's there ... I edited the question (added ts config files) :( that's the weird part

Comment: Have you tried to restart the ts server? (command `typescript.restartTsServer`)

Comment: I dont have any restart TS server ... however I restarted Volar Vue server (as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454845/where-is-vscodes-restart-ts-server ) ... didn't fix that